# Amazon AWS spot instance cheaper than reserved for 24x365 usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

Grasping amazon AWS pricing is complicated but this simply I cannot figure out:

Amazon reserved instances should be cheaper when used 24 hours a day for 365 a year than spot instances also used 24 hours a day for 365 a year, however my calculations don't fit this.

For instance let's consider m3.medium instances pricing with spot and reserved pricing:

**m3.medium spot instance:**

$0.0221 per Hour, $0.0221 * 8765,81 hours a year = $ 193 a year

**m3.medium light utilization reserved instance:**

$110 upfront plus 0,064 hourly * 8765,81 hours a year = $ 487 a year

Note: prices were taken from

```
  http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/reserved-instances/

  http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/spot-instances/
```

**EDIT:** I just realized spot instances and on demand instances are not the same thing, then why damn you Amazon don't you put all options in your left bar!!!!

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Amazon's pricing system.

Answer (score 7):

Spot instances can be a good deal, if you can architect your solution to deal with being terminated at any instant with *zero* notice - not all workloads can handle that. They are best for discrete tasks / units of work that can be started at any time and ended at anytime with no ill side effects.

SO your math is correct, but is not quite the whole picture - there is, IMO, a 0% chance that if you spin up a spot instance, with a price that gives you cheaper annual cost than a reserved instance, that it will stay running 24x7x365. Even if you bid a spot above the current reserved instance price, and hope that it averages below that, there is still next to 0% chance it will survive the whole year - best not to count on it and plan accordingly.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-instances.html

> To use Spot Instances, you place a Spot Instance request (your bid)
>   specifying the maximum price you are willing to pay per hour per
>   instance. If the maximum price of your bid is greater than the current
>   Spot Price, your request is fulfilled and your instances run until you
>   terminate them or the Spot Price increases above your maximum price.
>   **Your instance can also be terminated when your bid price equals the
>   market price, even when there is no increase in the market price.** ***This
>   can happen when demand for capacity rises, or when supply fluctuates.***

Comment: Where is it stated that they can terminate my instance at any time? I thought cloud was all about being 100% available all the time.

Comment: See my edits, they absolutely can and will terminate your instance without notice.

Comment: I just realized spot instances and on demand are not the same thing,, see my edit..

Comment: Notice that, even with On-Demand or Reserved instance, it is not true that *"cloud is all about being 100% available all the time"* -- the difference is that On-Demand or Reserved instances won't get terminated due to price fluctuations. However, failures are still possible, and you should design for that. *Design for failure, and nothing fails*. As Amazon's CTO, Werner Vogels, once said: "everything fails, all the time".

Answer (score 1):

You mention "Amazon reserved instances should be cheaper when used 24 hours a day for 365 a year than spot instances also used 24 hours a day for 365 a year" ... where did you get this information from? ... as in it all depends to the 'spot price' over the same period.

The decision whether or not to use 'spot price' instance is more dependant on the job in hand rather solely on 'cost', i.e. if you want to use a spot instance as e-commerce web server then this would be not be suitable based on the fact you may lose it at any time ... but if you had a job that updated stock levels every hour then 'spots' might be an option because if it never run for one hour then no worries we can try next time.

Here are some tips on using 'spots' : http://tech.just-eat.com/2014/02/13/tips-for-using-ec2-spot-instances/

Comment: "Using Light Utilization RIs, you can save up to 30% for a 1-year term and 49% for a 3-year term vs. running On- Demand Instances. The break-even point for a Light Utilization Linux RI (vs. On-Demand Instances) is 28% for a 1-year term or 11% of a 3-year term. If you expect to use your instance more than that, an RI will save you money." source: Amazon

Comment: That refers to 'Reserved' Vs 'On-Demand' ... no mention of 'Spots'.

'Reserved' instances are a 'Pay up front' for on-demand instances and 'Spots' are a 'Highest Bid Wins' for surplus on-demand instances

Answer (score 0):

Spot Instances allow you to bid for unused Amazon EC2 capacity. Instances are charged the Spot Price, which is set by Amazon EC2 and fluctuates periodically depending on the supply of and demand for Spot Instance capacity.

To use Spot Instances, you place a Spot Instance request, specifying the instance type, the Region desired, the number of Spot Instances you want to run, and the maximum price you are willing to pay per instance hour.

To determine how that maximum price compares to past Spot Prices, the Spot Price history is available via the Amazon EC2 API and the AWS Management Console

If your maximum price bid exceeds the current Spot Price, your request is fulfilled and your instances will run until either you choose to terminate them or the Spot Price increases above your maximum price (whichever is sooner).

Depending on current Spot Price and your Bid Price, a spot instance can be terminated immediately.  There is no guarantee your spot instance will run on 24x7 basis.  It all depends on the market.

There is no relation between Spot Prices and Reserved Instance prices.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague also falls into the same marketing traps of AWS reserved instances, which is even better : claims the corporate bulks discount reserved instances are even cheaper.

I never buy those word sparingly. Because SPOT instance is means to used for different application class. In fact, reserved instances ARE ALWAYS MORE EXPENSIVE than SPOT due to it supply demands natures. I already build apps that handle sudden task termination, and the apps are mean to do backend processing instead of serving front end.

SPOT instance does become MORE expensive , but it is not due to demands, but due to careless, incompetency. SPOT instance application should be build to stop ANYTIME, thus allow you to bid on the lowest possible stable price.  If you need continuous running system, reserved instance is the ONLY way to go.

If you sample SPOT history price for 4 regions (e.g. US-west, Sydney, Eu-West-1,ap-southeast-1， ap-southeast-2) ， you will notice mature region SPOT instance rarely jump into crazy spike price (e.g. from $0.02 jump to $5). It is simple math and rational thinking : there is no reason you bid a spot instance that cost more than default instance price. When you see that, you know there is yet another "noobish" with money to spend jump into SPOT to learn their lesson.

Even the "noob" willing to pay for crazy price, real SPOT devops can always jump to other regions to avoid the price race.